# WIX CustomAction terminates with error 1721 or 1722

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to create a MSI installer for my application which is a customized elasticsearch. I need to run `elasticsearch-service.bat install` command from cmd in the middle of installation. But whatever I do it will not execute successfully.

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallService" Directory="elasticsearch" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand='[SystemFolder] cmd.exe /c "bin\elasticsearch-service.bat install"' Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallService" After="InstallFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

1721 and 1722 errors are vague and do not contain any additional information. What is the reason for these error? I was suspicious that these errors are due to lack of admin privileges. But I add `InstallPrivileges=elevated` and `InstallScope=perMachine` to package element and still getting the same error.

Comment: MSI has built-in mechanisms to install services. Can you update your question with the content of the *.bat file so we can see what happens? Batch files should never be used in installers. No rollback, almost no error handling, very unreliable. Is the application written in Java?

Comment: Yes, the application is written in Java. There is some information about how to install elasticsearch as service in this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-service-win.html
I tried the built-in mechanism to create windows service but the service does not installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Stein, that you should use the **built-in** facilities of MSI/WiX to install the service, namely the [**`<ServiceInstall>`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html) and [**`<ServiceConfig>`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/serviceconfig.html) elements.

That being said, these are the errors of your current solution:

- Space between `[SystemFolder]` and `cmd.exe`.
- Executable path is not quoted.
- Relative path to .bat file. Very fragile.

**Possible solution:**

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallService" Directory="elasticsearch" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand='"[elasticsearch]bin\elasticsearch-service.bat" install' Return="check" />
```

You can call a batch file directly, without passing it to `cmd.exe`.